# split one fields into multi columns based value in other field

Tags: mysql, sql

My data is stored in mysql.

My Table data is as follows

```
3   credit  500.00
3   debit   500.00
4   credit  300.00
4   debit   300.00
5   credit  300.00
5   debit   300.00
6   credit  300.00
6   debit   300.00
```

I want to write a query to write data as
customer id, credit, debit,final_amount

where as final amount = credit-debit

Can someone please help me with query?

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are a community of volunteers offering aid to programmers stuck on a 
particular task. We are not a service to write free code for you. Please read 
[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I know that I have to use inner join. somehow not able to figure how.

Comment: Or just sit around while GL does everything for you, as usual.

Comment: @Strawberry Gordon needs those points.  Unless its actually an AI program created by Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Strawberry: LOL. Must be final exam time. Seen the same 5 or 6 questions (st least the task they're trying to do) fairly frequently lately.

Comment: :) LOL. last time i appeared for exam was 20 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select customerid, 
       sum(case when type = 'credit' then amount else 0 end) as credit,
       sum(case when type = 'debit' then amount else 0 end) as debit,
       sum(case when type = 'credit' then amount
                when type = 'debit' then - amount
                else 0
           end) as credit
from t
group by customerid;
```